# How to install PHP 8.1.13 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Tags: 22.04, php

If one installs PHP on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, by default PHP version 8.1.2 is installed:

```
$ sudo apt install php
$ php -v
PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.9 (cli) (built: Oct 19 2022 14:58:09) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.2, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.2-1ubuntu2.9, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

If I list what packages are available, I am told that version 8.1.13 is available as `php8.1`:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep php
…
ii  php8.1 8.1.13-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 all server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (metapackage)
…
```

However, if I try to install it, I am told that it is already installed:

```
 $ sudo apt install php8.1
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree... Done
 Reading state information... Done
 php8.1 is already the newest version (8.1.13-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
```

However, `php8.1 -v` (and the `php -v`  – it is symlinked) reports "PHP 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.9".

I also checked the binary, and it is definitively version 8.1.2.

For the record: This has nothing to do with the 7 packages reported as being kept back.

```
 $ sudo apt upgrade
 …
 The following packages have been kept back:
  grub-common grub-pc grub-pc-bin grub2-common libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db
  0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
```

I also tried to add the well-known `ppa:ondrej/php`.  It let me install PHP version 8.2.0, but *not* PHP 8.1.13 (or any other version 8.1.x).

I admit I don't understand what goes on here. Why does `apt install` tell me "php8.1 is already the newest version (8.1.13-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1)" when the `-v`option tells me otherwise?

Is there a way to install PHP version 8.1.13 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Comment: Generally, the most effective way to install a very specific version of any software is to use a Docker container. Everything else is transient or unreliable.